# Mapping a Cassandra Enum column to a non Name or Ordinal Value

Tags: enums, cassandra, datastax

I have an Enum

```
@AllArgConstructor
public enum SomeEnum {

SOMETHING (1,"ABC","xxx","yyy"),
SOMETHING_ELSE (2,"DEF","zzz","aaa"),
SOMETHING_ELSE_2 (3,"GHI","yyy","bbb")

final int val1;
final String value
final String val2;
final String val3;

}
```

I have a cassandra entity

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyClass;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class MyModel {

...........

..............

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "mycolumn", type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordinal = 1)
    private SomeEnum  someenum;
--------------
}
```

Now I want to save SomeEnum.value in cassandra `mycolumn` column
For example `ABC` not `SOMETHING`
and `DEF` not  `SOMETHING_ELSE` etc.

By default cassandra use `enum member name` for converting.

**So my Question is**
**How can I create a customerConverter for an `Enum` type column in cassandra Entity?**

Note-
In Java code, Entity class the column is of type enum as shown above, but in cassandra table `mycolumn` type is `TEXT`.